# Unable to render list values in html page from python script using flask framework

Tags: python, flask

I need to pass a list of values from python script to html page using flask framework.when I pass the values stored in a list variable, it prints only the last value of the list in the browser.
here is my python script-

here 'a' is the set of input and event is a list of unique class labels.

```py
app.route('/')

def output():

 DTC= DecisionTreeClassifier()

    DTC.fit(X_train,y_train)

    #print("output from DTC:")

    DTC.predict(pandas.DataFrame([a]))

    res=DTC.predict_proba([a])

    new=list(chain.from_iterable(res))

    index=sorted(range(len(new)), key=lambda i: new[i], reverse=True)[:5]

    for i in index:

          global value

          value=[]

          value=event[i]

    print (value) 

    return render_template('output.html',value=value)
```

And here is the output.html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <b><p>The output is:</p></b>
           {% for row in value %}
           <tr>
           <td> 
    {{row}}
    </td>

           </tr>
           {% endfor %}

    </body>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you reset each time value to an empty list:

```
value = []
for i in index:
      value.append(event[i])
```

Comment: still I am getting only one item from the list on my browser. Is there any problem in the html?

Comment: Are you sure that you have more than one event? Can you please check index and event? Use print len(index) and print len(event)

Comment: Yes I have 112 different event in the event column and index has the index value for each event.

Comment: and len(value) have 112 element?

Comment: You can check lengh of value inside the html with `{{value|length}}`

Comment: The length of value is 1 that is my problem index  contains 5 indexes I want the values of event on these indexes and render it in an html page to show on browser but I am always getting a single value not 5 values.